# Unable to instantiate driver class "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver": when deploying war file in jboss

Tags: java, mysql, jakarta-ee, jboss, jboss7.x

I have created a web application and the **database connection** is handled from using simple **jdbc connection** mechanism. after building the WAR file i have verified whether the **WEB-INF/lib** has the **mysql connector** library it was there and i am using **mysql 1.8 java connector**. but when i try to deploy the application in **jboss** i get sevral errors and warnings. project is build from java **1.7** and the jboss server runs with using same **jdk version.**

```
Unable to instantiate driver class "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver": 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver from [Module 
"deployment.NEWAPPLICATION.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
```

i have no idea why am i getting this error cz mysql connector can be found on the class path, and one of the other issue i am getting at the same stack trace is this

```
 Failed to define class com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver in Module 
 "deployment.NEWAPPLICATION.war:main" from Service Module Loader: 
 java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/mysql/cj/jdbc/Driver : 
 Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
```

and there are many logs which says couldn't index classes from **com/mysql/cj**

```
Could not index class com/mysql/cj/MysqlxSession.class at 
 /content/NEWAPPLICATION.war/WEB-INF/lib/mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar: 
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unknown tag! pos=32 poolCount = 334
```

I haven't really worked much with WAR applications and haven't really worked much with the Jboss servers as well. I can't figure out this on my own and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say that you're using Java 1.7, but it looks like the MySQL driver is compiled with Java 1.8.  Either upgrade your JRE, or find a driver compatible with Java 1.7.  You'll need Connector/J 5.1, rather than 8.  You can find this at [The MySQL Archive](https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/c-j/)

Edit: if you're using Maven, you can use this artefact:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.47</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Will i be able to connect to mysql version 8 using a 5.1 connector.

Comment: Yes you will (although perhaps not using SSL/TLS).  See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-versions.html